# too many rest api calls in Microservices

Tags: rest, web-services, microservices, loose-coupling

Say there are two services, 
service A and service B.

Service A needs data from service B to process a request. So as to avoid tight coupling we make a rest API call to the service B instead of directly querying service B's database. 
Doesn't making an HTTP call to the service B for every request reduces the response time?
I have seen the other solution to cache the data at service A. I have following questions.

1. What if the data is rapidly changing?
2. what if the data is critically important such as user account balance details and there has to be strong consistency.
3. what about data duplication and data consistency?
4. By introducing the rest call arent are we introducing a point of failure? what if service B is down?
5. Also by the increasing requests to service A for that particular API, service B load is also increasing.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

These are many questions at once, let me try to give a few comments in random order:

- If Service A **needs** data from service B, then B is already a single point of failure, so the reliability question is just moved from B's database to B's API endpoint. It's very unlikely, that this makes a big difference.
- A similar argument goes for the latency: A good API layer including caching might even decrease average latency.
- Once more the same with load: The data dependency of A on B already includes the load on B's database. And again a good API layer with caching might even help with the load.

So while the decoupling (from tight to loose) brings a lot of advantages, load and reliability are not necessarily in the disadvantages list.

A few words about caching:

Read caching can help a lot with load: Typically a request from A to B should indicate the version of the requested entity, that is available in the cache (possibly none of course), Endpoint B then can just verify if the entity has changed and if not stop all processing and just return an "unchanged" message. B can keep the information, which entities have changed in the immediate past in a much smaller data store than the entities themselves, most likely keeping them in RAM or even in process, speeding up things quite noticeably.

Such a mechanism can much easier be introduced in an API endpoint for B then in the database itself, so querying the API can scale much better than querying the DB.

Comment: Hi Eugen Rieck, Thanks for the answer. I have a question though, The approach you mentioned is fine with the small amount of data. What if the data is big and we need some operation such as sorting. e.g. what if I need the customer data along with the orders he has placed. So there are two services, Customer and Order service. So there is a join of data. And what if the order has to be sorted based on some fields?

Comment: Nothing in this list is hard: B needs a method to give a customer entity, one to give an unsorted list of order id/version tuples and one to give order entities by their ID. You now request the customer, the id list and the orders, caching everything. You can now sort the list inside the A endpoint and give back the results. On the next calls, you only need to update the list, then filter and sort, which can be done inside B. This helps massively reducing the load on A.

Comment: Hi Eugen Rieck, I didn't get this. Could you please elaborate more.

Comment: Which part do you have a problem with?

Comment: Nothing in this list is hard: B needs a method to give a customer entity, one to give an unsorted list of order id/version tuples and one to give order entities by their ID. You now request the customer, the id list and the orders, caching everything. You can now sort the list inside the A endpoint and give back the results. On the next calls, you only need to update the list, then filter and sort, which can be done inside B. This helps massively reducing the load on A  - This one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first question you should ask yourself is are A and B really two different services - what's the reason for partitioning them in the first place? After all, they seem to be coupled both temporally and by data.

one of the reasons to separate a service into two executables might be the can change independently or serve different access paths, in which case you may want to consider them different [aspects of the same service](http://%20https://arnon.me/2017/03/services-aspects/) - now this may seem like a distinction without a difference, but it is important when looking at the whole picture and which parts of the system can know about internal structures of others and defending the system into deteriorating to a big ball of mud where every "service" can access any other "service" data and they are all dependent on each other

If these two components are indeed different services, you may also consider moving to a model where service B published data changes actively. This way service A can cache the relevant parts of B's data. B is still the source of truth and A is decoupled from B's  availability (depending on the expiration of data)

Comment: Hi Arnon, Thanks for the answer. Suppose there are two services, Customer and Order service. I need customer data along with the orders he has placed. So So there is a join of data. And what if the order has to be sorted based on some fields? does caching order data at the customer service makes sense? also if the service who is owner of the data is emiting the events. and what if the updates are too frequent and there are too many events other service need to handle in order to keep data consistent. Another case is, what if the data is critical such as user bannk account transaction details?

Comment: It is rarely a good idea to partition services around business entities - it is like the samples for OOP are animal and cat etc. these are easy examples but since they are not partitioned around flows and data they tend to be chatty and overly dependent